# Flutter ImageShader

Tags: flutter

How do I create an `ImageShader` from a memory Image (`File image` or `Image.file`)?
Or in general, how do I create an ImageShader that I can use for `ShaderMask`. The examples given are
only using gradient shaders.

I'm trying to texture a bunch of `Text` using an image.